# Core plot - Y axis label formatting

Tags: ios, core-plot, axis-labels

I have my y axis range from -0.1 to 2.5 and want the y axis labels to be 0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0.

Currently this is what I have

```
newPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.1) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(2.6)];

CPTXYAxis *y = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.4);
```

But the above code also displays the label y = 2.4. I do not want 2.4 to be displayed on the y axis. Any suggestions as to how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided` labeling policy and set the tick locations you want or set the `labelExclusionRanges` to skip the label at 2.4.

Comment: +1, I used this - `y.labelExclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(2.1) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.4)], nil];` Thanks.